# How can I temporarily disable click events on a button without actually disabling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I would like to, without changing the `disabled` attribute of a given button, disable all click events for it.

I was thinking of retrieving the click event handlers, unbind them, and storing them (say, using `data()`).

Then I can re-bind them once the button is enabled again.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your approach - if you want a button not to work, disable it. That flags to the user clearly that the button is disabled. It's far neater, simpler and more consistent than working around the default behaviour. Why do you want to avoid disabling the button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not hard to do since jQuery already stores all of its event handlers as `data()` on the element itself. You can get (and modify) this object through `.data().events`.

Now you can easily save a reference to the handlers with:

```
 events._click = events.click;
 events.click = null;
```

And then restore them by using:

```
 events.click = events._click;
 events._click = null;
```

Note that this won't disable events that are bound via `.delegate()` or `.live()`, as they work by event bubbling/propagation. To disable those as well, simply bind a new handler that blocks propagation to ancestor elements:

```
 events._click = events.click;
 events.click = null;
 // Block .live() and .delegate()
 $("#el").click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

You don't even need to unbind this blocker function when it's time to enable the handlers again, since `events.click = events._click` will override the function you just bound with all the old handlers.

Comment: This kind of approach could be problematic. For one, I think I read somewhere that this behavior is not supported in new versions of jQuery. But even if that's not true, it's not a documented behavior, so I can't rely on it for future versions of jQuery.

Comment: @Ovesh, As an aside, I think Javascript is one of the languages, possibly due to its dynamic nature, de-facto "open source" (never compiled, only sometimes minified), and a history of browser incompatibilities, where there is less of an interest in hiding / protecting implementation details. As long as the risks are understood, and no better alternative exists, then feel free to dive in, modify prototypes, override functions, and in general.. hack away ;)

Comment: Agreed. I'll accept the answer, since there's probably no better solution.

Comment: It appears that this does NOT work anymore (as of jQuery 1.10, at least).

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another way:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("temp_disable") == "disabled") {
        //nothing to do, temporarily disabled...
    }
    else {
        alert("You clicked me!");
    }
});
```

To "disable" it for 10 seconds:

```
$("#myButton").attr("temp_disable", "disabled");
window.setTimeout(function() { $("#myButton").attr("temp_disable", ""); }, 10000);
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/ByM6h/

Comment: That's sort of what I ended up doing. But the problem is, it has to be added to every handler defined. From a design point-of-view, this is not a good solution, because some events may be added by code which is not in my control.

Comment: @Ovesh the only way to do it "globally" apart of really disabling the button is change it into something else e.g. `div` that only look like a button then change it back to button when the time expires - hopefully the event handlers will be preserved, need to check it first.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. You could replace it with a styled enabled button (with no click events attached), and keep the original button using `data()`. Then replace the original button back.

Answer (score 2):

That is the way to go. If you have onclick specified as an attribute you may switch the attribute busing

```
 $(button_element).attr('click', '');
```

and

```
 $(button_element).attr('click', 'do_the_regular_action()');
```

Comment: Assume that I don't know all the event handlers assigned to the element. And there might be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

All answers here are now outdated - as of jQuery 1.7 you should use `.off()` as explained [on the official jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>off demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  button#theone {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Add Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Remove Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>
 
<script>
function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .on( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Does nothing..." );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd accept this, but I'd like the example first edited to call off() without arguments, to show how it removes all attached events (without needing to keep a reference to them). That would more closely address the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind` and `bind`

`$('#control').unbind('click');`

and

`$('#control').bind('click', NameOfFunctionToCall);`

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question (though I could be wrong). From the sounds of it, there may be multiple click handlers, and he may not be able to get a reference to the handler for binding (e.g. anonymous function, or function in another scope).

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on the answer(s) offered by Barry and Thariama... which I think will satisfy Ovesh's objections:

You can add a namespace to your event binding.  That lets you refer to that specific event binding later, without colliding with other bindings.  I think this is cleaner than the accepted answer...  (To be fair, this may not have been available in jQuery at the time of the original question).

```
// A generic click handler:
$('.myButton').click(function() { ... });

// A namespaced click handler:
$('.myButton').bind('click.someSituation', function()  { ... });

// Later you can unbind only the handler you want by using the namespace:
$('.myButton').unbind('click.someSituation');

// The default click handler still works.
```

Comment: I guess I should have made it clearer in the question. There could be multiple click events, not all of which were bound by my code. 
This solution is not generic enough.

Comment: In my example the generic .click() is an event bound by some other code.  The namespaced .bind(click...) is in your code.  You can unbind your namepspaced click handler, without affecting other click handlers.

Comment: Ah, but the question says, I want to disable *all* click events on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this thing Use Core Javascript to do this task 
e.g. Look following example.

```
function MakeSaveDisabled(flg) {
    if (flg != null) {
        $(".btnpost").each(function () {
            this.removeAttribute("disabled");
            if (this.hasAttribute("oclickevt")) {
                this.setAttribute("onclick", this.getAttribute("oclickevt"));
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".btnpost").each(function () {
            this.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
            if (this.getAttribute("onclick") != null) {
                this.setAttribute("oclickevt", this.getAttribute("onclick"));
            }
            this.removeAttribute("onclick");
        });
    }
}
```

Save the javascript function in some temporary attribute and bind it when you required.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the events and then restore them, this seems to work (note that the _ may need to be omitted depending on the version of JQuery).

This example stops the bootstrap toggle on-change event firing, then triggers the toggle then resets the events to whatever were there previously.  You can do the same with click etc.

```
var events;
// Save change events associated with this control
events = $._data($(this)[0], "events").change;
$._data($(this)[0], "events").change = null;

// Do your stuff here
$(this).bootstrapToggle("off");

// Reset change events
$._data($(this)[0], "events").change = events;
```