# Get all events or cancel click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to find all events on my page in JavaScript so I can cancel some of them. For example, I have a scheduler that is using jQueryUI for drag/drop/resize, and that element that has class `".draggable"` also has a click function. Now, I want to prevent that click when I start drag/resize, and enable it after I finish drag/resize.

I tried multiple things but none of them work perfectly.

```
1. ui.helper.bind("click.prevent",
          function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
2. e.stopImmediatePropagation();
3. $( event.originalEvent.target ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
```

These all work, but only sometimes. Sometimes click gets triggered and sometimes it doesn't. Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594064/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-click-events-on-a-button-without-actually-disablin/9985349

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').off('click');
```

Will remove the click event (or whatever event specified) from the elements returned.